# pontiac g6 shut down

Tags: starting, pontiac, g6

I have a 2006 Pontiac g6 v6 3.5 engine and while driving my car shut completely down first thing popped on was the power steering then the steering wheel got hard to turn the anti-theft light came on the lights went dim and the car shut down we put a alternator and battery on it and the car worked for 30 mins and did the exact same thing and shut down has anybody else experienced this if so what can be going on

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest you don't have the battery attached very well. Make sure all connections are clean to battery and alternator. Also, you could have gotten a bad alternator from the store. It happens.

Comment: okay I just spoke with a gmc dealer who stated it could be a bad ground where as it wasn't cleaned or something before \after he put the altenator or battery on